# Testing Google login with Playwright returns denied sign in

Tags: node.js, playwright

I am trying to test google login but get redirected to `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth/deniedsigninrejected` instead to the `https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/challenge/pwd` part of the login. My code

```
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';

test('Entry', async ({ page }) => {
    console.log('Opening Asos.com')
    await page.goto('https://www.asos.com/');
    console.log('Hovering action menu')
    await page.hover('[data-testid=myAccountIcon]');
    console.log('clicking on Join')
    await page.locator('[data-testid=signup-link]').click();
    console.log('Opening registration page')
    await expect(page).toHaveURL(/.*identity\/register.*/);
    console.log('Clicking sign up by google')
    await page.locator('#signup-google').click()
    console.log('Opening google registration page')
    await expect(page).toHaveURL(/.*accounts.google.com.*/)

    const navigationPromise = page.waitForNavigation({
        waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"
    });

    await navigationPromise;
    console.log('Filling email')
    await page.waitForSelector('input[type="email"]');
    await page.type('input[type="email"]', "office.skylord@gmail.com");
    console.log('Clicking #identifierNext')
    await page.click("#identifierNext");
    await page.waitForSelector('input[type="password"]');
    console.log('Filling password')
    await page.type('input[type="password"]', "yourpassword");
    await page.waitForSelector("#passwordNext");
    console.log('Login with google')
    await page.click("#passwordNext");
    console.log('Success')
    await navigationPromise;
});
```

Comment: I guess that's because of captcha

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Didn't think of it actually. Will search in playwright if there is a way to bypass it for the tests.